# Googelbot finds my original URI, although I have a working rewrite directive

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, googlebot

I have :

```
RewriteRule ^Article/([^/]*)$ /article.php?newsid=$1 [L]
```

Which means that the URL must be `//example.com/Article/855563`
but Google crawls `//example.com/article.php?newsid=855563`.
Is there anything I can do to prevent this? Or to redirect 301 to `example.com/Article/855563`?

Comment: you might want to format your question properly, additionally i doubt you are the owner of domain.com, please use the properly designed domain for that (hint f.e example.com) for example look here https://www.iana.org/domains/reserved

as for your question, it is lacking a lot of information about your system.
read https://serverfault.com/help for details.

as for your question itself: test it yourself, curl/wget or similiar tools which are able to access your website are available and can be used to check if a rewrite rule is working properly.

Comment: From your question I understand that the google bot is Crawling //domain.com/article.php?newsid=855563 instead of //domain.com/Article/855563. 
Try - RewriteRule ^Article/([^/]*)$ /Article/$1 [NC,L]

Answer (score 1):

You first need to identify why Google is crawling the wrong URLs.

- Did you change an existing URL structure (that had been indexed by search engines and linked to externally)? In which case you would have needed to have implemented a redirect from the old URL to the new in order to preserve SEO and get search engines to replace the old URLs in the SERPs.
- Are you inadvertently linking to the wrong URL(s) internally and exposing the "wrong" URLs to search engines? If so, these *must* be fixed *before* implementing the redirect.

Otherwise, Google should not have been able to discover the "wrong" URLs.

You should also be implementing a `rel="canonical"` tag in the head of your pages to indicate the correct canonical URL to search engines.

In order to externally redirect a URL of the form `/article.php?newsid=<newsid>` to `/Article/<newsid>` (the canonical URL) - the reverse of the existing *internal rewrite* - then you can do something like the following near the top of your `.htaccess` file (*before* the existing rewrite):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^newsid=([^&]*)
RewriteRule ^article\.php$ /Article/%1 [R=302,L]
```

The first condition that checks against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable is necessary in order to prevent a redirect loop - it ensures that the rule is only processed on direct requests from the client and not rewritten requests (your existing directive).

The second condition captures the value of the `newsid` URL parameter (that occurs at the start of the URL path). This is saved in the `%1` backreference (used later in the `RewriteRule` *substitution*). Note that this captures *anything* (as in your rewrite), however, if the `newsid` value is always numeric then this should really be made more restrictive. eg. `^newsid=(\d+)` (1 or more digits only).

Note that this is currently a 302 (temporary) redirect. Only change it to a 301 (permanent) redirect once you have confirmed that it works OK - in order to avoid any caching issues.